# libwebsocket: unable to write frame bigger than 7160 bytes

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, payload, libwebsockets

I'm addressing an issue with WebSocket that I'm not able to understand.
Please, use the code below as reference:

```
int write_buffer_size = 8000 +
                LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING +
                LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING;

char *write_buffer = new unsigned char[write_buffer_size];

/* ... other code
   write_buffer is filled in some way that is not important for the question
*/

n = libwebsocket_write(wsi, &write_buffer[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], write_len,
            (libwebsocket_write_protocol)write_mode);
    if (n < 0) {
        cerr << "ERROR " << n << " writing to socket, hanging up" << endl;
        if (utils) {
            log = "wsmanager::error: hanging up writing to websocket";
            utils->writeLog(log);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (n < write_len) {
        cerr << "Partial write: " << n << " < " << write_len << endl;
        if (utils) {
            log = "wsmanager-error: websocket partial write";
            utils->writeLog(log);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

When I try to send data bigger than 7160 bytes I receive always the same error, e.g. **Partial write: 7160 < 8000**.
Do you have any kind of explanation for that behavior?
I have allocated a buffer with 8000 bytes reserved for the payload so I was expecting to be able to send a maximum amount of data of 8K, but 7160 (bytes) seems to be the maximum amount of data I can send.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See http://ml.libwebsockets.org/pipermail/libwebsockets/2013-September/000572.html

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be a different problem related to the rx buffer. In my case the issue appears writing (and not reading) to websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue updating libwebsockets to **1.7.3** version.
We also optimized the code using a custom callback called when the channel is writable

```
void
WSManager::onWritable() {
    int ret, n;
    struct fragment *frg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&send_queue_mutex);

    if (!send_queue.empty() && !lws_partial_buffered(wsi)) {
        frg = send_queue.front();

        n = lws_write(wsi, frg->content + LWS_PRE, frg->len, (lws_write_protocol)frg->mode);
        ret = checkWsWrite(n, frg->len);

        if (ret >= 0 && !lws_partial_buffered(wsi)) {
            if (frg->mode == WS_SINGLE_FRAGMENT || frg->mode == WS_LAST_FRAGMENT)
                signalResponseSent();

            // pop fragment and free memory only if lws_write was successful
            send_queue.pop();
            delete(frg);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&send_queue_mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem with an older version of libwebsockets. Although I didn't monitor the limit, it was pretty much the same thing: `n < write_len`. I think my limit was way lower, below 2048B, and I knew that the same code worked fine with newer version of libwebsockets (on different machine).

Since Debian Jessie doesn't have lws v1.6 in repositories, I've built it from [github sources](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/README.build.md). Consider upgrading, it may help solve your problem. Beware, they have changed api. It was mostly renaming of methods' names from libwebsocket_* to lws_*, but also some arguments changed. Check this [pull request](https://github.com/mnisjk/cppWebSockets/pull/2/files) which migrates *boilerplate libwebsockets server* to version 1.6. Most of these changes will affect your code.